# TypeError: this.model is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

this my code

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = (cb) => {
  console.log(this)
  return this.model("Animal").find({ type: this.type }, cb);
};

var Animal = model("Animal", animalSchema);
var dog = new Animal({ type: "dog" });

dog.findSimilarTypes((err, dogs) =>{
  console.log(dogs); 
});
```

When i write like that 
`function(cb) {
    return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
  };` everything is working.But when I use arrow function, i get error .

> TypeError: this.model is not a function

Can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

It is because arrow function do not have their own **this**. And it is binding their context lexically.

As you have used **this.model** within your arrow function and it is not the instance of that file/ controller, **this** will point to the window object. This will result in the error that your this.model is not a function.

I hope it clears your doubt.